# parsing deserialized application/vnd.ms-excel in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xls, aws-lambda

I have application/vnd.ms-excel (xls) object in memory. No option to save it to disk. I need to parse it but all the libraries I found are taking file path as a parameter.

Any experience/ideas what to use to process the content of the xls?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx worked for me:

```
var xlsx = require('xlsx');
var workbook = xlsx.read(data.Body, {type:"buffer"});
```